# How to access variable values outside for loop and display to user in dialogflow using nodejs

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-es

Conversation Flow:

User:hi,I want to book a hotel.
Bot:sure.tell me your minimum range.
User:110$.
Bot:your maximum range?
User:180$.
Bot:I see the  hotels of range 110$,145$,180$.Which one you would like to select?

Here,I use firestore db to retreive the data from database that ranges from 110$ to 180$.

Code below:

```
const snapshot = await db.collection('hoteldetails').where('Price', '<=', maxnumber) .where('Price','>=',minnumber).get()
      var result=snapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data());      
      if(result.length!=0){
      for(let i =0;i<result.length;i++)
        {                               
            var hotelname=result[i].HotelName;
            var city=result[i].City;
            var price=result[i].Price;                                                    
        }
        console.log("price",price);
```

Result:(console.log("result",result)):-retrieves the records from Firestore.

```
result [
  {
    Price: 100,
    Availability: 'Yes',
    City: 'Mumbai',
    HotelName: 'GrandHyatt'
  },
  {
    HotelName: 'Leelaplace',
    Price: 110,
    City: 'Banglore',
    Availability: 'Yes'
  },
  {
    HotelName: 'OberaiHotel',
    City: 'Mumbai',
    Availability: 'Yes',
    Price: 150
  },
  {
    HotelName: 'Taj Hotel',
    Availability: 'yes',
    Price: 180,
    City: 'Mumbai'
  }
]
```

If I use console.log(price) after for loop,I get only last record price displayed-180$...I tried using push .But It did not work.

I am beginner to Nodejs. How can I display all the prices from result array  as shown in above conversation flow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways you could achieve the result that you want.

Here are some ways on how you can do it:

1. You can put the `console.log("price",price);` within the for loop.

```
const snapshot = await db.collection('hoteldetails').where('Price', '<=', maxnumber) .where('Price','>=',minnumber).get()
      var result=snapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data());      
      if(result.length!=0){
      for(let i =0;i<result.length;i++)
        {                               
            var hotelname=result[i].HotelName;
            var city=result[i].City;
            var price=result[i].Price;  
 
            console.log("price",price);                                                 
        }
```

The code above will print the price on each loop that its making.
It should give you this result:

```
price 100
price 110
price 150
price 180
```

You could test the code **[here](https://www.jdoodle.com/ia/i0h)**.

2. You can use array push.

```
const snapshot = await db.collection('hoteldetails').where('Price', '<=', maxnumber) .where('Price','>=',minnumber).get()
      var result=snapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data());      
      if(result.length!=0){
      var prices = [];
      for(let i =0;i<result.length;i++)
        {                               
            var hotelname=result[i].HotelName;
            var city=result[i].City;
            var price=result[i].Price;  

            prices.push(price);
        }

        //".toString()" converts array to string. You can remove ".toString()" if you want it as an array.
        console.log(prices.toString());
```

You can test the code [here](https://www.jdoodle.com/ia/i0p).

Please check this **[Loops and iteration](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration)** guide for more information about looping.

Comment: Thanks !The second one worked...and thanks for the Iteration guide you shared....It will be helpful for me to understand the basics